# Object cannot be assigned to other types from DBNull

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, dbnull, executescalar

I get minimum number in my database. But when no data in my database I get this error.

> System.InvalidCastException: 'The object cannot be assigned to other types from DBNull.'

Code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(GidenEvrakSira) FROM GidenEvrak", con);    
SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("Select Min(GidenEvrakSira) FROM GidenEvrak Where UserID is null", con);    

con.Open();    

maxnum = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
minum = Convert.ToInt32(smd.ExecuteScalar());    

con.Close();
```

Comment: Sorry. What is the error message you are getting? Please edit your question and add the exact text of the error message.

Comment: If there is no data, `Min(...)` and `Max(...) ` return the value DBNull. You have to check for such NULL values before handing the result to `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: Cast DBNull to null.  So try something like this : var results =  (cmd.ExecuteScalar == DBNull.Value) ? null : cmd.ExecuteScalar

Comment: Yes it work. Thanks @jdweng

var results = (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == DBNull.Value) ? null : cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jdweng suggestion in comment is working:

```
var results = (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == DBNull.Value) ? null : cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: This executes the command twice, not a good practice, spacially if the command writes data. Consider placing the output of `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

At run-time (tested under ODP.NET but should be the same under any ADO.NET provider), 
it behaves like this:

If the row does not exist, the result of `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` is null, which is then casted to a null string and assigned to getusername.
If the row exists, but has NULL in username (is this even possible in your DB?), the result of `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` is DBNull.Value, resulting in an `InvalidCastException`.
In any case, the `NullReferenceException` should not be possible, so your problem probably lies elsewhere.

Comment: No. I'm sure the problem is here. It just needs to be in an if loop. I couldn't find this way. :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to always return a value by surrounding the max/min with `ISNULL` function.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT isnull(MAX(GidenEvrakSira),0) FROM GidenEvrak", con);    
SqlCommand smd = new SqlCommand("Select isnull(Min(GidenEvrakSira),0) FROM GidenEvrak Where UserID is null", con);    

con.Open();    

maxnum = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
minum = Convert.ToInt32(smd.ExecuteScalar());    

con.Close();
```